# Find the eigenvalues of $TMT^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I've been stuck on this question for a while, can anyone help?
I don't understand how you can find the eigenvalues of $TMT^{-1}$ using the polynomial given by $p_M$. I know that the determinant of $M$ is zero.

For question $b$, I'm not sure if you can compute its determinant directly by subtracting 1 from the determinant of $M$. If you have to do it in some different way, I'll be glad to hear how to do it. Below, I've listed my question. Cheers!

Let *M* be a 3 x 3 matrix with the characteristic polynomial $p_M$($l$)= $l^{3} - l$.

a) Let *T* be a nonsingular matrix. Find the eigenvalues of $TMT^{-1}$. Is it diagonalizable?

b) Find the eigenvalues of $M - $$I_3$ where $I_3$ denotes the 3 x 3 identity matrix.

Comment: Hint. $M$ and $TMT^{-1}$ are similar. The two matrices have the same geometry, described in different coordinate systems.They have the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: Thank you for making this clear. I thought it might be something like that. Cheers!

Comment: I still need help for b though. It is vague for me.

Comment: @EthanBolker similar matrices do have same eigen  values but not necessarily same Eigenvectors.

Comment: @AnuragA Well, yes and no. The linear transformation is the same, so the eigenvectors are the same. But the matrices and the vectors as tuples of coordinates with respect to a changed basis are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigen vector for $M$ corresponding to the eigen value $1$, then $M\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$. Also say $T(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{w}$. Then by non-singularity of $T$,we have $T^{-1}(\mathbf{w})=\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w} \neq \mathbf{0}$. 
\begin{align*}
TMT^{-1}(\mathbf{w}) & = TM\mathbf{v}\\
&=T\mathbf{v}\\
&=\mathbf{w}.
\end{align*}
Thus $\lambda=1$ is also an eigen value of $TMT^{-1}$. Hope you can take it from here.

**for(b).**

Using the same notation as above. Consider
$$(M-I)\mathbf{v}=M\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}.$$

Thus corresponding to the eigen value $1$ of $M$, $M-I$ has eigen value $0$. Now proceed for the other eigen values.